# ASP.NET localization stopps after around 60 minutes

Tags: c#, asp.net, iis, localization

We have an application based on ASP.NET MVC 5.2 and we're using localization with Resource files (resx), `Localization.resx`, `Localization.de-DE.resx`, `Localization.de-AT.resx`, `Localization.en-US.resx`, `Localization.en-GB.resx`... etc etc which produces satellite assemblies.

We determine the language first by cookie and then as fallback by browser header information. Works very well.

```
protected internal void Application_BeginRequest(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    HttpCookie cultureCookie = httpRequest.Cookies[CookieName.Culture];
    string cultureName;
    if (cultureCookie != null)
        cultureName = cultureCookie.Value;
    else
    {
        if (httpRequest.UserLanguages != null && httpRequest.UserLanguages.Length > 0)
            cultureName = httpRequest.UserLanguages[0];
        else
            cultureName = null;
    }

    cultureName = CultureHelper.GetImplementedCulture(cultureName); // returns default on null

    Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = new CultureInfo(cultureName);
    Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture = Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture;
}
```

We use the `Localization.PropertyName` directly in views like

```
<div class="text-right">@Localization.Header_TopMenu_Service</div>
```

This works fine so far but after around 60-80 minutes we have a problem on just one environment (productive): the localization does not work anymore.
It effects just these textes! The thread still has the correct culture!

Internally we still work with the `Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture` values like for static texts, calculations of taxes... and this still works.
So some parts of the application are now in english (static stuff and logic stuff like calulcation of taxes) and all elements from the `Localization` resources are in german (default).

Why can this happen?

We thought there is something with race conditions but we've embedded some information to the output and everything is fine:

```
<!--
CurrentCulture == 'en-GB'
CurrentUICulture == 'en-GB'
ManagedThreadId == '25'
IsThreadPoolThread == 'True'
-->
```

Even if the language in this output is en-GB the localization outputs our default ,which is german.

When we restart or recycle the application, the localization works for again 60 minutes.
We also tried to set the language via Filter or in the Controller: same issue.

What can be the reason for this weird issue?
Wrong implementation? Something with satellite assemblies? IIS issue? system configuration?

Because everything works fine on the test stage and this effects just occur on the prod (no new build, just a copy) I think it is something with the system.

Comment: Did you look at your logs ? (Windows Logs, application log, etc.). You indicate that it stop working after 60-80 min but after what ? the application startup ? do you have any caching mechanism ?

Comment: @CyrilDurand as described 60 minutes after appliction (re)start or recycle. No caching here. We have integrated the current timestamp to the html output to eliminate all doubt about output caching

Comment: I have found something.. In our `AssemblyInfo.cs` is the line `[assembly: NeutralResourcesLanguage("en")]`.
We do not have a language `en`, we only have `en-GB` and `en-US`. Also there is missing the `UltimateResourceFallbackLocation.Satellite` but we have no fallback in our main dll. Can this be the reason?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Problem is solved.

It was a race condition which set `Localization.Culture` (or in other implementations `Resources.Culture`) globally to a specific language.
The problem was, that this should be null in web applications. If this is null, `ResourceManager.GetString()` uses `Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture` for localization.

If  `Localization.Culture` is not null the ResourceManager does not care about `Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture`.